Query two SQL databases in the same Jupyter instance using jaydebeapi
I need to query two different databases in the same Jupyter notebook. The code below works great for each individual database section (Informix V Oracle), but when I run all commands, I get an error at jaydebeapi.connect for the second query (Oracle). The error I get is:

TypeError oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver is not found.

But again this chunk of code does work if I reset the kernel and I run the Oracle section first and then the type class error will appear at jaydebeapi.connect for Informix.
So the Informix and Oracle chunks of code work just fine independently… but something doesn't seem to like my combined efforts. What do I have wrong? Can I not query two different databases in the same notebook/kernel?
I ensured the individual connections/code to Informix and Oracle completely execute ruling out bad code. Each chunk executes when run independently, but when run together in the same notebook, I get a type error class.
import jaydebeapi
import pandas as pd
#First database query
driver =             “com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver”
url= “”
jdbc_driver_path = [“i.jar”]
Conn = jaydebeapi.connect(driver, url, [“username”, “password”], jbdc_driver_path)
Cursor = conn.cursor()
# run query here
Conn.close()
Cursor.close()
#Run 2nd connection/query 
driver =             “oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver”
url= “”
jdbc_driver_path = [“o.jar”]
Conn = jaydebeapi.connect(driver, url, [“username”, “password”], jbdc_driver_path)
Cursor = conn.cursor()
# run query here
Conn.close()
Cursor.close()


You should probably close the cursor before you close the connection; after the connection is closed, there is no way to access the cursor.  Does it work any better if you use driver1 and driver2, and similarly with the other variables that you're 'reusing'?  (I know recycling is great, but sometimes you don't want to do it.)  I've not used any of the Python packages you're using, so I could be completely off the mark here.

Good ideas to try, but neither these two things individually (nor combined) solved the issue.

I'm not surprised that the suggestions didn't help.  The order of closes is a cosmetic issue of sorts.  If you checked the 'close cursor' operations, they should report failure because the connection is no longer available (at least, that's what I'd expect).  I've no experience worth mentioning with Python and these database access packages; I'm sorry I can't help much.

Delete the close calls and use with context blocks to implicitly close resources.  Also why not use the python-oracledb driver?
